# How to deploy URL encoded picklist values in record types through ant?

Tags: picklist, record-type, ant, url-encode

In the metadata the picklist definition has the not URL encoded values of:

```
A  $100 million+
B  $50 - $99 million
```

And in the record types definition the values have been automatically URL encoded when retrieving with ant becoming:

```
A  %24100 million%2B
B  %2450 - %2499 million
```

Therefore, when deploying with ant I get the errors:

```
Picklist value: A  %24100 million%2B in picklist: Rating not found.
Picklist value: B  %2450 - %2499 million in picklist: Rating not found.
```

I have tried manually reverting the URL encoded values in record types to be exactly as they are in the picklist definition (not URL encoded), but I still get the exact same errors.

I have tried manually URL encoding the values in the picklist definition to be as they are in recordtypes, and still get the same errors.

NOTES:

Curiously enough, this happens only in the Rating standard field on Account object but not in the Rating__c on the Contact object. Even though the metadata is the same (picklist definition not url encoded and record type picklist value is url encoded).

This error only happens when deploying with ant. If I compile (save) the files with Mavensmate it's successfully saved.

Any clues?